# WSO2 API Manager vs Micro Gateway

Tags: .net-core, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am planning to use WSO2 as my API Gateway.

Requirement
We have created .NET Core APIs for our microservices and need to use Gateway for manage APIs.

I am totally confused by whether to use API Manager or WSO2 Micro Gateway  or do we need to use both together

Can anyone help me in this regards

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 API Manager is a full life cycle API management solution that also consists of an API Gateway, which serves API requests. However, this API Gateway was not originally designed for the container world. Therefore, this gateway can be a bit bulky for a container.

The solution is the Microgateway, which is designed for the container world. It is very lightweight and container-native. Microgateway can be used with the API manager to manage APIs.

Here[1] you can read more details about when to use each gateway.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Overview+of+the+Microgateway

Comment: Thanks for you for your reply. I am having horrible time to configure wso2. Do you have some experience in adding multiple apis to WSO2 and have the jwt token mechanism

Comment: Yes, where are you stuck? You can create questions for each specific blocker you find.

Comment: I posted my queries as a question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726653/wso2-jwt-authentication-and-gateway-grouping