# WSO2 JWT Authentication and Gateway grouping

Tags: .net-core, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have been trying to configure WSO2 API manager as our API Gateway. I am facing below issues while configuring and testing.

1. Authorization of apis migrated to WSO2
2. Getting JSONObject["exp"] not found. when trying to access API with Token
3. Not sure about the client ID which has to be given for Authorization URL: https://localhost:8243/authorize
4. Is this URL: https://localhost:8243/authorize is the one we use for authenticate the APIs
5. Have used carbon for creating users, Service and Identity providers,  Are they related to each other and how can we use it for the JWT authentication
6. Is this subscription means creating a user for using API?
7. How i can group multiple APIs into a microgateway

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Please follow the QSG in APIM. That will help you understand the basic usecases. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/GettingStarted/quick-start-guide/

Comment: Thanks, I have followed these steps. My doubt is how we authenticate via a client..
suppose i want to authenticate first
http://localhost:8243/token 

where do i create credentials?

Comment: You can either create users ( https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Users ) or  plug a userstore.